# extract data in csv from table with 2 billion records

Tags: java, oracle, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

Wanted to know the tool which can extract data in csv from a table or by executing a sql query like

```
select * from table 1 inner join table 2 on ...
```

Data is currently in oracle database and required to be extracted in csv and processed through Java code and after processing final csv/multiple csv files required to be loaded back to same oracle database .

Is there any tool script does this task efficiently

Comment: Just about any programming client environment that has hooks into a database can do this. Perl, PHP, python, C++, Java, etc.. whatever. Even SQL*Plus, though that isn't very efficient. Just connect, query, fetch, and then use string concatenation to write out a CSV.

Nothing that Oracle itself provides with the database will do this for you. In the past folks tried using utl_file but it's slow, writes only to the database host and is a security hole. This is a task for a client programming language outside the database.

Comment: You sure want to extract 2B rows into a csv file to do some processing, and then load into the DB? I would try as hard as I can to write the processing in SQL and do t in the DB.

Comment: Agreed: if you can do SQL set operations on that many rows instead of row-by-row processing outside the database, your performance will be better by multiple orders of magnitude.

Comment: The requestor specified that the data was *required* to be extracted to csv for file processing. The requestor may have reasons for this not shared, so while it is pertinent to suggest reconsidering this architecture, it's still legit to ask how such a file can be made.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very bad idea. Anyway, you can use the ODBC Driver "Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)" which should be available on each Windows.

Setup the connection in ODBC Administrator `odbcad32.exe`

[image]

[image]

And then you can select the data with any generic ODBC capable SQL tool, e.g. [WinSQL](https://web.synametrics.com/winsql.htm) or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)